# My web form is not saving to database successfully

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, forms

My form doesn't save the text in the Texbox to the database. I've probably something wrong in my .cs CodeFile, but I can't work it out.

It could well be my connection string.

**My web form:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Enter selection text:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here is my code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=db65225900.db.1and1.com; Initial Catalog=db211255182; User ID=dbo652259000; Password=Password");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into homepageSelection values('"+TextBox1.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();    
    }
}
```

My MsSQL is setup like the following:

1 column: selectionText nvarchar(3000)

Comment: Your insert query is wrong

Comment: It will work if table contains only one column

Comment: are u getting any error?

Comment: Did you get any error messages when debugging? Insert statement should be like this: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try to use `insert into homepageSelection (**YOUR_COLUMN_NAME**) values`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing button click event definition in aspx

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
                                             ---------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlConnection` is for SQL Server. You need `MySqlConnection` - This is not part of the .NET Framework. So it is a better approach if you will also have to use the `MySqlCommand` object rather than the `SqlCommand` object.

This is **MySql** and not **SQL**. So you need to get connected to MySql. For this you need to download and installed the MySQL Connector/NET from the [MySQL official website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html).

Then probably you can look at [Connect C# to MySQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) to see how to get connected with MySQL Database and run the different Insert, Update, Select, Delete commands using C#

Last but not the least you have to include `OnClick="Button1_Click1"` with your `asp:Button`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the colum name in insert statement

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into homepageSelection (ColumnName) values('"+TextBox1.Text+"')";
```

also you missed click event

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
```